# Double Integral Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let function $f(x, y)$ be deﬁned by
$$f(x, y) =\begin{cases}
1,\text{ if }x = y,\\
0,\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Using the deﬁnition of the double integral show that the following integral exists and that: $$\iint\limits_R f \, dA = 0.$$

Comment: I had no idea how to format the last equation sorry. Perhaps can you explain it better? What's RR R?

Comment: Sorry, That's the double integral fdA over the region R. R is an arbitrary region.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what is you definition of double integral, but this is an approach that should be comprehensible anyway: pick $\varepsilon>0$ and build very small squares around the line $y=x$, let us say that the side of each square is $\varepsilon$. Now the maximum of $f$ in each square is 1, and the minimum is $0$. Then
$$
\int_R f\, d\mathcal{L}^2 \approx \sum_{\mathrm{finite}} (1-0) \varepsilon^2,
$$
which is arbitrarily small. The sum is finite because the region $R$ is bounded.

Comment: I see, does the summation go to 0 as epsilon goes to 0?

Comment: Well, since it is a finite summation, it give a multiple of $\varepsilon^2$.